# Deactivate inline chunk output cache in RStudio

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio

I have a .Rmd file with the following content

````
```{r, cache=FALSE}
x <- rnorm(10)
plot(x)
```
````

and running it in RStudio gives the output [image]

If I save the file, close RStudio and open the file again, the output is still there despite the `cache=FALSE` setting. How can I deactivate that the plot, or chunk output in general, is cached and not displayed If the .Rmd file is opened the next time? Where is this cache stored on my system?

Comment: `cache` refers to something else than what you might think. It doesn't mean "hidden". You may find this useful: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/chunk-options.html

Comment: I know that `cache` actually refers to whether code is re-run if the notebook is knitted, but I thought RStudio would pick it up as well to decide whether the output is cached when the .Rmd is re-opened. I believe it's an RStudio functionality (hence the rstudio-tag), becaue the .Rmd is only a text-file and the plot cannot be stored there.

Comment: But the whole notion of `cache` gets thrown out the window once you are using `rnorm()` without setting a seed. I don't understand what your expectation is.

Comment: I would like that if I open an .Rmd file, only the code chunks are displayed and not the code plus the chunk output from the last time I ran the .Rmd. I updated my question and hope it is clearer now.